# Application crashes when I execute Keyboard.SetShifted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash, keyboard

I am trying to make a custom soft keyboard, my problem comes when I try to use the method setshifted of my keyboard, application get crashed.

Here is my output error:

> 02-19 19:58:45.649 2222-2222/? E/InputEventReceiver: Exception
>   dispatching input event. 02-19 19:58:45.649 2222-2222/?
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback 02-19 19:58:45.649 2222-2222/?
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   length=0; index=0
>                                                          at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:584)
>                                                          at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:578)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.adjustCase(KeyboardView.java:577)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onBufferDraw(KeyboardView.java:687)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.invalidateKey(KeyboardView.java:1054)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1348)
>                                                          at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1209)
>                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
>                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3978)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3857)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3423)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3450)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3423)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3450)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3423)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5626)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5606)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5577)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5706)
>                                                         at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dis 02-19 19:58:45.649 2222-2222/?
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 02-19 19:58:45.649 2222-2222/?
>   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x94c9bb20) 02-19 19:58:45.649 2222-2222/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: app.parkinghelper.com.parkinghelper11, PID: 2222
>                                                    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                                                        at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:584)
>                                                        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:578)
>                                                        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.adjustCase(KeyboardView.java:577)
>                                                        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onBufferDraw(KeyboardView.java:687)
>                                                        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.invalidateKey(KeyboardView.java:1054)
>                                                        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1348)
>                                                        at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1209)
>                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
>                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7886)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3978)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3857)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3423)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3549)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3450)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3606)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3423)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3450)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3423)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5626)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5606)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5577)
>                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceive

Constructor of the keyboard class

```
ph_ckb_2(Activity host, View kbview, int viewid, int Layoutid1) {

        mHostActivity = host;
        m_RootView = kbview;
        i_kbid1 = Layoutid1;

        kb_1 = new Keyboard(mHostActivity, i_kbid1);

        mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView)m_RootView.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(kb_1);
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);

        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        hideCustomKeyboard();

    }
```

Input function

```
    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {              
        View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();

        assert focusCurrent != null;

        Class<? extends View> GetTextClass = focusCurrent.getClass();

        if (GetTextClass == AppCompatEditText.class || GetTextClass == AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.class) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            if (primaryCode == CodeShift) {
                bShifted = !bShifted;
                mKeyboardView.setShifted(bShifted);
                mKeyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();                   
            } else { 
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
            }
        }
    }
```

Original code here
[Crea un teclado personalizado en Android](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)
and here 
[Android development: Custom keyboard](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm)

Comment: can you narrow the code down to a [mcve]? There is a lot of code here and it would appear much of it is not necessary to ask your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, the problem is only when I press the shift key and mKeyboardView.setShifted(bShifted); is triggered

Comment: Please, if you need something else, just let me know, i have many days searching for an aswer

Comment: @JorgeE.RamírezGuillén Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious bug in the `adjustCase` method that leads to `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception for empty strings.

```
private CharSequence adjustCase(CharSequence label) {
    if (mKeyboard.isShifted() && label != null && label.length() < 3
            && Character.isLowerCase(label.charAt(0))) {
        label = label.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
    return label;
}
```

Comment: Its not too obvious for me, I'm new making custom keyboards, if "adjustCase" is a standard method, how do I fix the problem? , im guessing that the problem is here "Character.isLowerCase(label.charAt(0))"

Sorry for my ignorance :c

Comment: Exactly, you're right about the exception location. There should be an extra condition in the if : `label.length()>0`.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you do not have a Key with an empty Label. If it is empty, then this bug will occur.

For example this will cause a bug:

```
<Row android:horizontalGap="0%p" android:keyHeight="0%p">
    <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="" android:keyWidth="100%p" />
</Row>
```

Comment: I should note that if you do want a key with no Label, you can try just having a space in it.